# Emailing Reports using ACRA(ver 5.7.0) on Android not working

Tags: acra

Im trying to capture the crash logs and send it via mail using ACRA. But the mail is not received.

I have done the following :

**1.  Initialized ACRA inside the oncreate method of the main activity**

```
ACRA.init(getApplication());
```

**2. Specified the Report content**

```
@AcraCore(reportContent = {
        ReportField.REPORT_ID,
        ReportField.USER_APP_START_DATE,
        ReportField.USER_CRASH_DATE,
        ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
        ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
        ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
        ReportField.DEVICE_ID,
        ReportField.BRAND,
        ReportField.BUILD,
        ReportField.DEVICE_FEATURES,
        ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
        ReportField.REPORT_ID,
        ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
        ReportField.APPLICATION_LOG,
        ReportField.LOGCAT,
        ReportField.USER_EMAIL
},
        reportFormat = JSON,
        reportSenderFactoryClasses = {MainActivity.ACRASenderFactory.class}

)
```

**3. Acrareportsender class below**

```
public class ACRAReportSender implements ReportSender {
    public ACRAReportSender(){
        Log.e("ACRA", "Report Sender created");
    }
    @Override

    public void send(Context context, CrashReportData crashReportData) throws ReportSenderException {
        Log.e("ACRA", "Before sending crash report");
        String reportBody = createCrashReport(crashReportData);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
        String mail[] = {"brajesh.poovakkad@gmail.com"};
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mail);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, reportBody);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ACRA Crash Report");
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send crash to developers by email ..."));
    }
    public String createCrashReport(CrashReportData crashReportData){
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        body.append("Device : " + crashReportData.getString(ReportField.BRAND) + " - " + crashReportData.getString(ReportField.PHONE_MODEL))
                .append("\n")
                .append("Android Version : " + crashReportData.getString(ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION))
                .append("\n")
                .append("App Version : " + crashReportData.getString(ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE))
                .append("\n")
                .append("STACK TRACE : \n" + crashReportData.getString(ReportField.STACK_TRACE));
        return body.toString();

    }
}
```

**4. AcraSenderFactory Class**

```
public class ACRASenderFactory implements ReportSenderFactory {
    public ACRASenderFactory(){
        Log.e("ACRA", "Creating Sender Factory");
    }

    @NonNull
    public ReportSender create(Context context, CoreConfiguration acraConfiguration) {
        Log.e("ACRA", "Returning Report Sender");
        return new ACRAReportSender();
    }
}
```

**Output as verified from logcat ( provided below)**

```
1. 09-01 20:36:06.063  3938  3938 I ACRA    : ACRA is enabled for com.example.myapplication, initializing..    

2. ACRA    : ACRA caught a RuntimeException for com.example.myapplication     

3. 09-01 20:36:06.529  3938  3938 D ACRA    : Building report
09-01 20:36:06.535  3938  4022 D ACRA    : Calling collector org.acra.collector.LogCatCollector
09-01 20:36:06.536  3938  4020 D ACRA    : Calling collector org.acra.collector.DropBoxCollector
09-01 20:36:06.536  3938  4020 D ACRA    : Collector org.acra.collector.DropBoxCollector completed
09-01 20:36:06.536  3938  4020 D ACRA    : Calling collector org.acra.collector.ReflectionCollecto..................
.......................

....................
ACRA    : ServicePluginLoader loading services from ServiceLoader : java.util.ServiceLoader[org.acra.sender.ReportSenderFactory].......
...........................................
...........................................
09-01 20:36:06.586  3938  4010 D ACRA    : Ignoring disabled ReportSenderFactory of type EmailIntentSenderFactory
09-01 20:36:06.586  3938  4010 D ACRA    : reportSenderFactories : []
```

............................................................................
............................................................................

```
09-01 20:36:06.590  3938  4010 D ACRA    : Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@1d3f9ef against plugin class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
09-01 20:36:06.590  3938  4010 D ACRA    : Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@b426cfc against plugin class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
**09-01 20:36:06.591  3938  4010 D ACRA    : Ignoring disabled ReportSenderFactory of type HttpSenderFactory**

..............................................................
.............................................................
.............................................................
09-01 20:36:06.616  3938  3938 D ACRA    : Ignoring disabled ReportInteraction of type NotificationInteraction
09-01 20:36:06.616  3938  3938 D ACRA    : Mark 2020-09-01T20:36:06.565+05:30.stacktrace as approved.
09-01 20:36:06.617  3938  3938 D ACRA    : Schedule report sending
09-01 20:36:06.626  3938  3938 D ACRA    : config#reportSenderFactoryClasses : ImmutableList{[]}
09-01 20:36:06.626  3938  3938 D ACRA    : Using PluginLoader to find ReportSender factories
```

**The above logs says**

```
a. Acra is getting initialized
b. acra is catching crash
c. report is approved
```

**Query:**

```
  **1. Where am i going wrong. why is it not sending mail**
  2. Is this, **"Ignoring disabled ReportSenderFactory of type HttpSenderFactory"**, as seen from the logs, the reason for not receiving reports via mail? If yes, how this can be rectified ?
```

**Note: in manifest file, Internet permission is provided**

Answer (score 1):

Your `ReportSenderFactory` cannot be an inner class. Either make it a toplevel class or declare it static. It also must not be abstract.

Comment: i have moved the ReportsenderFactory to top level class and removed static. Still the reports are not coming to my mail. I'm initializing ACRA ( ACRA.init ) in the main activity class, have reportsender and senderfactory class in two different files. My question is , when i initialize ACRA, does it run seperately in a different thread than the app's main thread and monitor the app thread for any exceptions and catch them whenever it happens and send the report ? or does it need to be specifically invoked inside the main activity class

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup?

Comment: Thanks... It worked...i was missing some of the basic setup points